# App crash when react-native-mapbox-gl in release mode

Tags: react-native, react-native-mapbox-gl

App is working fine in debug mode and it is crashing in release mode
When we go the map page and apply zoom in or zoom out the app is crashing

```
<MapboxGL.ShapeSource
          onPress={res => this.storeSelectedValues(res)}
          id={'line' + i.toString()}
          shape={this.state.routes.features[i]}>
<MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
            id={'symbol' + i.toString()}
            style={{
              iconImage: require('../../asset/images/marker.png'),
              iconSize: 0.05,
            }}
          />
</MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
```

Comment: Can you show us some log?

Comment: See this https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/388

Comment: Also this https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl/issues/1088

Comment: @AnasM.I Thanks for giving reply. I am using the texture mode to display the maps. In one plus devices the marker is getting black color when we zoom in and in redmi mobiles the app is crashing in release mode but it is working fine debug modes